# Bulk Insert wont work unless I save CSV again

Tags: sql, r, bulkinsert

I have downloaded data in R and put it in a CSV which I want to insert into a database.

```
set nocount on Bulk Insert dbo.Raw_BM086_Daily_Meter_Data_Report 
from 'C:/Filename.csv
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='\n',BATCHSIZE=250000,MAXERRORS=1);
```

I am getting the following error when I run the Bulk Insert query in SQL Server.

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (ID).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (ID).
Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (1) was exceeded.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 41
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

The table is structured as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Raw_Table(
ID BigINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1), 
Date Date,
Participant varchar(32),
ResourceName varchar(32),
ResourceType char(3),
StartTime Datetime,
EndTime Datetime,
Jurisdiction char(3),
Meter numeric (8,3),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

The raw data looks as follows:
[image]

```
Date    Participant ResourceName    ResourceType    StartTime   EndTime Jurisdiction    Meter
```

1   20200723    PT_400109   GU_401350   GEN 2020-07-23T19:30:00 2020-07-23T20:00:00 XYZ 0.329
2   20200723    PT_400087   GU_401230   GEN 2020-07-23T19:30:00 2020-07-23T20:00:00 XYZ 8.519
3   20200723    PT_400085   GU_401140   GEN 2020-07-23T19:30:00 2020-07-23T20:00:00 XYZ 0

When I open the CSV and save it, without doing anything else and run my BULK Insert query it works perfectly.

It is very frustrating- I want to automate the process and avoid saving the CSV manually to get the Bulk Insert to work

Comment: are you using SQL 2008?

Comment: if you using SQL 2008, there is only one way to fix this issue and that is to upgrade. SQL 2008 cannot load UTF-8 files, it is as simple as that. You need at least SQL 2014 SP2.

Also, if you don't want the double quotes around the text in the first record to be included, you need to raise the stakes to SQL 2017 which is the first version to support the CSV format for real.
For a longer discussion on this topic see [the article Using the Bulk-Load Tools in SQL Server.][1]


  [1]: http://www.sommarskog.se/bulkload.html

Comment: Thanks - I am using 2019 SQL Express. I can use the Bulk Insert, but only after saving the CSV....without making any changes

Comment: @user1966593, can you better explain as your last comment is not clear? Is issue resolved? Your issue appears to be encoding problems. Please post sample data.

Comment: When you say you "open the CSV and save it", what do you "open" it with? A text editor? Or, as for many people, does it get opened by Excel by default? If the latter, Excel is making changes to your file when you save it.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaug - I run the Bulk Insert code - I have tried this directly in SQL but also using R. I get the error message. I open Excel, save the CSV without making any changes and close Excel. Run the Bulk Insert in SQL and R and it loads the data perfectly??

Comment: Hi @Parfait -I have updated with more data and an example- hopefully its clear